# Pass a string to various websites

Tags: input

I have a product code which I need to enter into 6 different websites in order to pull different information from them about the product. Is there away to save this product code into some sort of variable and pass it into each websites input box and it return all the information from each one automatically? Really have no idea where to go/start with this so if anyone can brainstorm a few ideas to get me moving that would be great.

Comment: Programming language? The general idea is that you will make an appropriate HTTP request to each server (you will have to "reverse engineer" the correct format for each request) and parse the HTML response (you will also have to find the correct parse for each), preferably using some XPath implementation, to get back the info you want.

Comment: The only issue with this is that the request format may change at any time. Still, unless the website has some sort of API, this is probably the only way to go about it that I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order get what you are planning for:
You need a script which visits the specified web site,
then at the website, you can get the element by tag.

For instance in javascript, 
    var textBox = document.getElementByTag(Input);

This will give you a reference to text field to enter the text. It can be done as follows:

```
textBox.value = "any string";
```

Once you have done this, you will have to retrieve the results from the page, based on the website layout.
So if you can specify about your work in detail, you would get better response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about using an ordinary GUI browser, the best you can do is copy it to your system clipboard, and paste it into each page on the browser.

If you're talking about a programmatic web-access like wget or curl, it depends on what language you are writing your script in.

Comment: I don't have any language in mind yet its going to be which ever is the most effective at getting the job done. No matter which way I look at it its going to be messy without any direct access to the databases to run any SQL against it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the web request for each web site and find a way to parse the response which will be HTML

have a look at the `HttpWebRequest` you can find lots of example on internet that shows how you can create an HTTP POST to a website.

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/